# JavaScript file names are getting changed after building using "ng build" command in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, express

I am new to Angular. I see that, there are some files like runtime.js, polyfills.js, main.js, styles.css etc getting generated by Angular cli when creating a new project.
When I build the app using ng build command, inside the dist directory, I am getting similar files with a random number added in these file names like main.some_random_number.js

Is there any configuration that will stop this file name change? I am having issues on accessing these files through Express.js path since I don't know what file name will be after I run ng build command.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular is cache busting the files, so that when you deploy a new version, there is no chance that, old code will be viewed in your browser.

If you want to cache bust your application, you need to toggle the flag.

`--output-hashing` - controls addition of the cache busting random string.

As per angular documentation.

> --output-hashing   Define the output filename cache-busting hashing mode.
>
> none | all | media | bundles

So set it to none to remove the hash.

You can either set it in the command `ng build --output-hashing=none` or in the `angular.json` configurations array